# How to get number of child nodes in Selenium JS

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm web scraping a web site for a small project of mine and I want to get the number of faculty names.
The names are in the `<tr>` tags under the `<tbody>` tag.
I want to push the faculty names in to a list and right now I'm doing it with a hardcoded number of faculties that are currently on the site. That's ok for now, but the number might change and I want my code to work if they add more faculties.

```
var listOfFaculties = [];
for(var i = 2; i <= 18; i++){ // start with inedx 2 and go to 18 (from the first to the last faculty on the site) -- HARDCODED
    await driver.findElement(By.xpath(getXPath(i))).getText().then(function(value) {
        listOfFaculties.push({
            Faculty: value
        });
    });
}
function getXPath(num){
    return "//div[@id = 'main']/center[2]/font[@class='normal']/table/tbody/tr[" + num + "]/td[1]";
}
```

Is there a method to get the number of child nodes of `<tbody>` tag? So I can put the number in to the for loop without hardcoding the bounds.

Comment: You can execute script `"return arguments[0].childNodes.length;"` where `arguments[0]` is target `tbody` node

Comment: @Andersson thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Use List of `WebElement` to get the faculty length.

Your revised code should be like -

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id = 'main']/center[2]/font[@class='normal']/table/tbody/tr"));

var listOfFaculties = [];
for(var i = 2; i < elements.size(); i++){ 
    await driver.findElement(By.xpath(getXPath(i))).getText().then(function(value) {
        listOfFaculties.push({
            Faculty: value
        });
    });
}

function getXPath(num){
    return "//div[@id = 'main']/center[2]/font[@class='normal']/table/tbody/tr[" + num + "]/td[1]";
}
```

Comment: How do you get List<WebElement> elements in javascript?